# Copy XML file from Server to iphone?

Tags: iphone

I want to copy the xml file from server to save it to locally, because if I will send request to server again and again, it will take time, so I want to copy the xml to local resources whenever app starts, then parse the local xml,

how can I do it?

Comment: Are you coding for WebKit or a Cocoa app?

Comment: Why would you need to copy the XML file? It suggests to me it either doesn't change (so you just bundle it in the app) or it doesn't change as often as you're polling the server (so poll less).

Comment: xml will change time to time, but if i will access making connection, then it will slow down, so i want to copy to directory in iphone, then use it,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to download the file:

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:FILEURL];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

then add in the h file:

```
NSMutableData *receivedData;
```

and in the m file:

```
    -(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
    {
        if (receivedData)
        {
            [receivedData appendData:data];
        }
        else 
        {
            receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithData:data];
        }
    }

    -(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
    {
        //saving your data in the local

        NSString *docDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *fullName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"xmlfile.xml"];

        NSString *fullFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",docDir,fullName];
        [receivedData writeToFile:fullFilePath atomically:YES];

    }
```

edit:
get the file from local-

```
NSString *docDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *fullName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"xmlfile.xml"];

        NSString *fullFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",docDir,fullName];
NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

now you can take the NSData when parse it,there are a lot of examples in the site.

Comment: and how will parse the file, just the file name pass to nsxmlparser?

Comment: THnx, is there speed difference while you parse from net and locally?

Comment: no there is not speed difference, because you do it on NSdata, the speed difference is in download the file